# Snowflake Kafka connector config issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm following the steps in this guide [Snowflake Connector for Kafka](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/kafka-connector.html#label-schema-of-table-for-snowflake-kafka-connector)

The error message I'm getting is

**BadRequestException: Connector config {.....} contains no connector type**

I am running the command as

```
sh kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties snowflake_kafka_config.json
```

my config files are

connect-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/Users/kafka_test/kafka
```

jar file `snowflake-kafka-connector-0.5.1.jar` is in `plugin.path`

snowflake_kafka_config.json

```
{
  "name":"Kafka_Test",
  "Config":{
    "connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"8",
    "topics":"test",
    "snowflake.topic2table.map": "",
    "buffer.count.records":"1",
    "buffer.flush.time":"60",
    "buffer.size.bytes":"65536",
    "snowflake.url.name":"<url>",
    "snowflake.user.name":"<user_name>",
    "snowflake.private.key":"<private_key>",
    "snowflake.private.key.passphrase":"<pass_phrase>",
    "snowflake.database.name":"<db>",
    "snowflake.schema.name":"<schema>",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source":"",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info":""
  }
}
```

Kafka is running on local, I have a producer and consumer up, can see the data flowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same question I answered over on the [Confluent community Slack](http://cnfl.io/slack), but I'll post it here for reference too :-)

---

The connect worker log shows that the connector JAR itself is being loaded, so the 'contains no connector type` is because your config formatting is fubar.

You're running in Standalone mode, but passing in a JSON file which won't. My personal opinion is always use distributed, even if just a single node of it. Check this out if you need a recap on standalone vs distributed : http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect

If you must use standalone then you need your connector config (`snowflake_kafka_config.json`) to be a properties file like this:

```
param1=argument1
param2=argument2
```

You can see valid JSON examples (if you use distributed mode) here: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-connect-zero-to-hero/demo_zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect.adoc#stream-data-from-kafka-to-elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I am using standalone for test purposes, will be using distributed for production

Comment: I'd recommend not doing that - stick with distributed throughout, including for test. Easier to standardise config and understand how to run it the same across all envs. Just my £0.02p on the matter.